# How to get hash tag in javascript SRC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

Is there easy way to get the hash tag in script source?

Example:

```
<script src='myscript.js#result=5235'></script>
```

I want to get the variable `result=5235` using `myscript.js`

Comment: I think it is a very easy question. use jquery.

Comment: Do you want to get it inside the containing document, or the called script file itself? (i.e. do you need the key-value `result=5235` inside the `myscript.js` as a dynamic parameter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/h6Zzw/

You'd probably want to use a more specific selector than that, but it gets the point across.

Edit: Why did you tag jQuery if you don't want jQuery?

Pure: http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/h6Zzw/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var hash = $('script').attr('src').split('#')[1];
```

or

```
var hash = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].src;
    hash = hash.split('#')[1];
```

assuming it's the first script, otherwise change `[0]` to whatever index the script has.

Comment: interesting one liner @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

```
           var srcVariable = $(script).attr("src");
           var hashText = srcVariable.substring(srcVariable.indexOf('#'));
```

Comment: @RommerDelaCruz I think you got the answer.

Comment: @OP for future plz do not tag "jquery" if you want pure JS answer, like it says in the SO help docs. (jquery tags implies you will accept JQuery solutions)

Answer (score 0):

For this example suppose you want to do your operation of getting that result=whatever to all of your script tags on your page. Do something like below:

```
var whatever = [];

$('script').each(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   var splitonhash-arrReturned = src.split('#');
   var yourAnswer = splitonhash-arrReturned[1];
   whatever.push(yourAnswer);
});
```

PURE JS example:

```
var whatever = [];

var items = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (i=0; i< items.length; i++)
{
   whatever.push(items[i].attributes.getNamedItem("src").split('#')[1]); 
}
```